# Function stored to a variable not running when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, trumbowyg

I'm working on a plugin for Trumbowyg where I'm trying to store a function in a variable so it can be called later but also be over-writable without altering the included javascript file.

The problem is, the function is not being called when I try to call it.

Here is my relevant code:

```
init: function (trumbowyg) {
    
    var plugins = trumbowyg.o.plugins;

    ...
    
    if(!plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal) {
        plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal = function() {
            console.log('close modal');
            $(plugins.giphycrumbs.modal_selector).modal('hide');
        }
    }
    
    $(document).on('click', '.add_giphy', function() {
        trumbowyg.execCmd('insertImage', $(this).attr('src'), false, true);
        
        plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal;
        
    });
    
    // If the plugin is a button
    trumbowyg.addBtnDef('giphycrumbs', {
            //this function is handled exactly the same way except it actually works
        fn: plugins.giphycrumbs.open_modal
    });
}
```

In my code above, you can see I am checking if `plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal` is NOT set, and if thats true, I set it to a function which is supposed to close a modal.

In my click handler for `.add_giphy`, the `insertImage` code works, but `plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal` is *never* executed (I don't get the `console.log` message embedded in the function)

If I do `console.log(plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal)` the expected function is put into the console.

Why is the `close_modal` function not executed in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Try adding parentheses to `close_modal` inside your click handler.

### Explanation

It seems to me like you are not invoking (calling) this function.

In your click handler, there's this line `plugins.giphycrumbs.close_modal;`

In javascript, this is a reference to a property on the `giphycrumbs` object. Though it happens to be a function, it will not be invoked as such unless you use parentheses after it (and optionally give it some arguments).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, doesn't that make _me_ feel dumb.

Comment: I know the feeling  It does illustrate how a function is just a javascript object like any other until you call it!

Comment: If this helped, it would be great if you can accept it as an answer 